# Dual (DVI) monitor setup for MacBook Pro 15" (Retina mid-2015)

Tags: macbook-pro, dual-screen

I am looking for a solution to connect a MacBook Pro 11,4 (15" retina model from mid 2015) to two monitors. The present question is different from prior questions on dual monitor for Macbook Pro, as it is for a specific model (specific ports) and monitors with specific connections.

Both monitors have VGA and DVI connections, but my MacBook Pro has two ThunderBolt ports and a HDMI port.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connect MacBook Pro to two external monitors](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/195215/connect-macbook-pro-to-two-external-monitors)

Comment: @Allan I disagree on the comment about duplication. I have specified why in my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to purchase 2 mini-DisplayPort to DVI cables. Connect the DVI end to the monitor and the mini-DisplayPort into the Thunderbolt ports on the MacBook Pro.

Comment: Do you know of any docking solutions as an alternative?

Comment: Yes, there's lot of dock options available from Belkin, Elgato, OWC, etc. Check out a list here: http://www.macworld.com/article/2920233/laptop-accessories/thunderbolt-2-docks-roundup-connecting-multiple-devices-to-your-mac-laptop-has-never-been-easier.html