# How to chian two External Monitors with Macbook Air 2017 13"

Tags: display, hdmi, displayport

About the Mac:

```
Mac OS Mojave
Version 10.14.4 (18E226) 
MacBook Air (13-inch, 2017)
```

I wish to connect two external monitors with following specifications with my Apple device.

```
one pure HDMI 
other VGA (converted to HDMI using a VGA to HDMI Adapter)
```

My device has one mini-display port. I have bought a (not an apple product) 3-in-1 mini-display port to (DVI, HDMI, VGA) adapter.

I have two options to connect.

```
1. Connect pure HDMI, VGA based monitors into one 3-in-1 mini-display port adapter. (FAILS!)
2. Connect the pure 3-in-1 Adapter to a splitter (another device that accepts one HDMI input and spilts into 4 HDMI outputs) using HDMI cable and then connect the two monitors using HDMI outputs. (WORKS!)
```

The second method is able to connect two monitors but my Apple device shows only one device connected in `Display Settings` and **the two external monitors mirror each other but I want a chain display**.

Any help?

Comment: Though the linked question is about a 2015 MBA, the specs are still the same so it’s a possible duplicate of [Early 2015 MacBook Air and two external monitors: how to do it and maximum resolution?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/325735/early-2015-macbook-air-and-two-external-monitors-how-to-do-it-and-maximum-resol)

Answer (score 1):

The 2017 MacBook Air does not natively support dual external displays. When you connect a monitor through the mini-DisplayPort, you'll only get a single display. Even when using the splitter - you'll always get a single display mirrored across both monitors.

The 3-in-1 mini-DisplayPort adapter is meant for converting the DisplayPort signal to one of three other signals - but only one at a time!

I would suggest using your existing adapter to connect the HDMI monitor to the MacBook Air using the mini-DisplayPort on the MacBook Air. Then buy a DisplayLink VGA adapter for connecting the VGA monitor to the MacBook Air's USB-port. Note that this display won't have the same performance as the built-in display and the HDMI monitor - so if you're using this for intense gaming applications, you'll probably want a different computer.

Comment: "Then buy a DisplayLink VGA adapter for connecting the VGA monitor to the MacBook Air's USB-port." I want to use it for programming purposes. Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes, I have used DisplayLink VGA adapters before...